In Google Cloud console, safe to grant Firebase Admin SDK role to default compute service account?
In order to use the Firebase Admin SDK in v2 Firebase Cloud Functions, one must grant the "Default compute service account" in Google Cloud console the "Firebase Admin SDK Administrator Service Agent" role. This is because v2 functions use this service account to access the Firebase Admin SDK and not the "firebase-adminsdk" service account that was automatically created with that aforementioned role.
Is it safe to grant the default compute engine service account this role? Or is there a way to force v2 functions to use the firebase-adminsdk service account instead?

Whenever you are granting extra permissions to anything at all, it could be considered "unsafe" without understanding the bigger picture of all the cloud components in involved, and their individual security configurations.  To be specific, if you grant this permissions, we have no idea what other parts of your project might be impacted.  So it's really not possible, given the information here, to say if it's "safe" or not.
As a best practice, you should observe the principle of least privilege, and only assign the most specific required permissions to any component based on its actual needs.  That is the only thing that could be considered universally "safe".
If you want your Cloud Functions code to be as "safe" as possible, you should initialize the Firebase Admin SDK with a service account that has been granted only the specific permissions required to do whatever you need to do with the SDK.  This means you're going to have to pass an AppOptions parameter to initializeApp with appropriate service account credentials.

The AppOptions interface can take a service account ID string. Would you consider this a "safe" way to designate which service account to use? The alternative, using the Credential interface, appears to require the use of keys, which I really would like to avoid.

You must provide a full credentials object.  It won't work any other way. serviceAccountId is a different thing for a different purpose.

Would you be able to link me to an official or unofficial tutorial for how to initialize the app with service account credentials for v2 functions? I can't find anything anywhere.

There is already a link in my answer on how to init the SDK. The API docs I linked also have everything you need: "When authorizing via a service account, you have two choices for providing the credentials to your application. You can either set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable, or you can explicitly pass the path to the service account key in code"

The link says that in order to initialize the Admin SDK, "a configuration file with your service account's credentials" is needed. There are no instructions about this file beyond the fact that it needs to exist. Can you link me to something about this config file?

The instructions on how to get a service account are in the same document.  Please read it carefully: "To generate a private key file for your service account:..."

And if you have a followup question, please post it separately.  It doesn't make sense to continue here indefinitely in comments.  Also note that service accounts are a GCP concept, and there is plenty of extra documentation about them in the GCP docs.  The Firebase Admin SDK just extends what Google already provides for GCP.
